# Using SendCloud with 'X-SMTPAPI' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email

I hope this post will help someone.I need to use [SendCloud](http://sendcloud.sohu.com/) to send emails through smtp.At the begin i add header in ActionMailer:

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = JSON.dump({"to" => emails, "sub" => {"%name%" => names}})
```

But it can't work, and i also can't receiver the return error code through Rails.Then i find the way through communication with their support:

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = Base64.encode64(JSON.dump({"to" => emails, "sub" => {"%name%" => names}}))
```

But it also can't work correctly.Then i compare the generated headers["X-SMTPAPI"] with the sent headers["X-SMTPAPI"], and found Rails insert '\n' in it for format.In the end, [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/fields/unstructured_field.rb#L191) convert the '\n':

```
def encode_crlf(value)
  value.gsub!(CR, CR_ENCODED)
  value.gsub!(LF, LF_ENCODED)
  value
end
```

So, if i want it's success, i need to do like this:

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = Base64.encode64(JSON.dump({"to" => emails, "sub" => {"%name%" => names}})).gsub!(/\n/,'')
```

Wow, i can send 'x-smtpapi' header in Rails successfully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by encode and replacing '\n':

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = Base64.encode64(JSON.dump({"to" => emails, "sub" => {"%name%" => names}})).gsub!(/\n/,'')
```